# ConnectionError: There was a problem with the response body: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground, ada

I am having an issue with compiling any contracts on the local playground. It doesn't matter even when trying to compile the example contracts that are provided I keep getting this error. I have no idea what could be wrong, please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the server part of the playground is not running properly.

It could either be it hasn't started correctly and needs another start attempt. Retry the steps here to start the plutus-playground-server https://docs.plutus-community.com/ *(or if you're on a new mac, take a look here: https://github.com/renzwo/cardano-plutus-apps-install-m1)*. The server needs to be kept running in parallel in a separate window while using the playground.

Or I found a very old issue that suggests it could also be related to your disk being full: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/issues/1243. So that might be worth checking also.